# How to download subreddit json file and read into R as a data.frame

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I went to `https://www.reddit.com/r/sports/new.json` to download a json file to analyze in R.

Once I get into R, I use `library(jsonlite)` to read in the file, but when I try to convert to a dataframe, it gives me an error and says `arguments imply differing number of rows`

Here is my code:

```
library(jsonlite)

result <- fromJSON("new.json")
df <- as.data.frame(result)
```

I am open to using other packages as well if they prove more useful than jsonlite.

Comment: That doesn't look like a very rectangular input format. What exactly do you want the data.frame to look like?

Comment: I really just want to focus on what the post says, who said it, and a timestamp